# ctags not indexing all the words I want

Tags: vim, ctags

I'm trying to indexing my rails app with ctags so that vim can give me autocompletion.
However, ctags is not indexing all the words, especially my call to external library.
For example:
I have this file:

```
class MultipleChoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :options, :class_name => 'MultipleChoiceOption', :foreign_key => :parent_id, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options, :allow_destroy => true

  def question
    Question.find_by_data_id_and_data_type(id, MultipleChoice.name)
  end

  def randomized_options
    (0...options.size).to_a.shuffle.map{|index| [index, options[index]]}
  end

  def realized_answer(user_answer)
    user_answer.blank? ? nil : options[user_answer.to_i].content
  end

  def answer
    options.detect{|o| o.correct}.content
  rescue => e
    HoptoadNotifier.notify(
      :error_class   => "MultipleChoice",
      :error_message => "Exception while call #answer: #{e.message}",
      :parameters    => {:multiple_choice_id => self.id}
    )
    nil
  end
end
```

Then ctags would index MultipleChoice (class name), answer (method name) but not HoptoadNotifier.

I'm indexing with `ctags -R *`

Is there away to tell ctags to index them all?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you have the HoptoadNotifier source somewhere in your rails app directory. So, let's assume within your directory you have this:

```
/railsapp/vendor/plugins/hoptoad_notifier/lib
```

which would be where the HoptoadNotifier source is stored.

Then run the following commands:

```
cd /railsapp
ctags -R --tag-relative=yes
```

That will create a file within railsapp/ called tags and will contain the tag info of the HoptoadNotifier module.

I know that appears to be more or less what you have already done, so I can only assume that the HoptoadNotifier source isn't within your directory structure, because I recreated this on my machine and it worked perfectly. You can also run ctags with a "-V" to spit out all the debug info and what it's doing.